# Listing files in a directory with Python when the directory is huge

Tags: python, file, sorting, directory, size

I'm trying to deal with many files in Python. I first need to get a list of all the files in a single directory. At the moment, I'm using:

```
os.listdir(dir)
```

However. This isn't feasible since the directory I'm searching has upward of 81,000 files in it, and totals almost 5 Gigabytes.

What's the best way of stepping through each file one-by-one? Without Windows deciding that the Python process is not responding and killing it? Because that tends to happen.

It's being run on a 32-bit Windows XP machine, so clearly it can't index more than 4 GB of RAM.

Any other ideas form anyone to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try using the [`scandir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) module:

> `scandir` is a module which provides a generator version of `os.listdir()`
>   that also exposes the extra file information the operating system
>   returns when you iterate a directory. `scandir` also provides a much
>   faster version of `os.walk()`, because it can use the extra file
>   information exposed by the `scandir()` function.

There's an [accepted PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) proposing to merge it into the Python standard library, so it seems to have some traction.

Simple usage example from their docs:

```
def subdirs(path):
    """Yield directory names not starting with '.' under given path."""
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
            yield entry.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to avoid reading the entire list of filenames into memory. This returns a generator object allowing you to step through the filenames in your directory one by one:

```
import glob

files = glob.iglob(pathname\*)

for f in files:
    # do something with f
```