# How to extract the first file from each subdirectory of a given path and store it in a list?

Tags: python

A path is given and this path contains sub directories like

```
---- Folder1
---- Folder2 
---- Folder3
etc.
```

I want to extract from each folder the first file and store it in a list and if possible remove that file also from that folder.
I know how to do this by looping through folders and the respective files using os.listdir method but this process loads all the files in the memory.

And considering there are large number of files in each folder does anyone know an efficient way or method to loop through folders and extract the first file of each sub folder into a list.?

Comment: Take a look at [path.py](https://pathpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), that could help (note you'll have to install this library with `pip`, this is not a builtin)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550919/listing-files-in-a-directory-with-python-when-the-directory-is-huge) would be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory might help.

Comment: What is the first file here? Or more exactly what is the order? Lexicographic, modification time, the first in the folder internal structure, ...?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the first file in each sub-directory is an image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all subfolders of the given folder with [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk) function. Then you can extract each first file you need. Here is the example for first lexicographical files:

```
import os

result_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_folder):
    if files:
        result_files.append(sorted(files)[0])
```

Each tuple in `os.walk` contains:

- Current folder name
- All folders in the current folder
- All files in the current folder